# loading jquery ui-tab at bottom of html and tab repainting issue

Tags: jquery-ui

On a particular page, I am using jquery ui tab to tabify my web page. My JavaScripts are placed in external files and loaded at the end of my HTML. On document ready event, the very first thing I do is to call the tabify plugin.

The problem is that the browser has already painted the page at this point, then repaints it once it tabifies the page. So, I get a split-second flickering of the screen. How do I prevent this flickering? I do not want to load JavaScripts in  as I am trying to optimize my site per Google PageSpeed/Yahoo YSlow recommendations.

```
<html>
<body>
....

<script src="tabify.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

tabify.js

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hide the content with css `display:none;`  then use `$("#tabs").show().tabs();`

Comment: i tried using this but problem is it kidda flickers every time user clicks on another tabs, doesn't look that smooth specially as i am also using nested tabs